# What causes the Faraday effect, on a material level?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

I understand that the Faraday Effect is due to the velocity of propagation for left and right circularly polarized light being different in many optically-transparent dielectric media when exposed to an external magnetic field. This makes good intuitive sense, however it isn't clear to me *why* the external magnetic field induces circular birefringence.

**What is the magnetic field "doing" to the e.g. optically transparent glass such that it now has the property of circular birefringence, and why is the angle of rotation of the polarization linear in the magnetic field strength (as in $\theta = VBL$)?**

All sources I'm able to find seem to skip right to assuming that the B-field somehow induces circular birefringence, discuss linear polarization as a superposition of circular polarizations, and simply give the $\theta = VBL$ formula. **How do we get to this formula?**

Comment: Actually, one has to first ask you what you would accept as an answer to your question. After all, it is usually accepted that the mathematical derivation of the observed effect is an explanation. Or would you want to go into polaritons and other complicated explanations of the behaviour? We cannot deduce what you would accept.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm looking for a sufficiently motivated mathematical derivation of the observed effect (i.e. of the Becquerel equation $\theta=VBL$), although answers which include and go beyond this would be great as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to look into what happens to paramagnetic impurities in something like flint glass, or if it a gas in optical cell, the paramagnetism of the gas.

If there is an unpaired electron, then there is a magnetic moment. When the field is applied it applies a torque to that magnetic moment, as a result there is a small change in the refractive index that is dependent on the magnetic field direction.

At a slightly deeper level this is the Zeeman effect and for the the applied magnetic field if you looked very closely you would see splitting of the energy levels of the impurity atonm. This is essentially changing the absorption of the light passing through the material (imaginary part of the dielectric constant), and the refractive index is related to the the real part of the dielectric constant. The imaginary part and the real part of the dielectric constant are related to each other through the Krammer-Kronig relations.

So ultimately it is these small changes that give you a Faraday effect.

Comment: The question asked about a transparent glass, and "why"  The hyportnex is an answer to a different question, and the I think wraps up the physics in the magnetic susceptibility. Leaded glasses are heavy or light given the amount of impurities, and have larger or smaller Verdant constants. However, I think my answer is pretty shallow. You have Faraday effect in diamagentic materials or crystals etc. and the details of the material matter. In general though https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.pc.17.100166.002151 is an older review, but is an idea of the oscillator approach.